# Spark 2.2.0: How to remove Specific Duplicates from a Dataset of a list column

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

GoodMorning to everyone and have a nice a day. I have a dataset like below

```
+-----+------------+
|Text2|Set         |
+-----+------------+
|seven|[3]         |
|one  |[1, 5, 2, 3]|
|six  |[5]         |
|five |[5, 2, 4]   |
+-----+------------+
```

What I would like to do is remove specific duplicates from the set of Colum. For example, let’s assume I want to remove number 3 and 4 together.

Imagine an output like above. As we can see both 3,4 deleted from every row of the column Set

```
+-----+------------+
|Text2|Set         |
+-----+------------+
|one  |[1, 5, 2]   |
|six  |[5]         |
|five |[5, 2]      |
+-----+------------+
```

What is the most efficient way to do it with the Dataset api? because let’s assume that I need this operation for a large data

From what i am thinking is to map first and the perform a reduce as the most efficient way to achieve it but I am not sure that what I am saying now is a stupidity solution.

Here is my Java code example

```
 List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create("seven", Arrays.asList(3)),
                RowFactory.create("one", Arrays.asList(1, 5, 2, 3)),
                RowFactory.create("six", Arrays.asList(5)),
                RowFactory.create("five", Arrays.asList(5, 2, 4))
        );

        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("Text2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("Set", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType), false, Metadata.empty())
        });

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        df.show(false);
```

I would be grateful if someone will give me a solution base on my problem

Comment: You need to only remove 3 and 4? Will the elements that you want to remove be a part of a List ? If so, you can write a UDF to check if the array that you passed contains the columns, filter the ones that don't match the List you want to skip.

Comment: Does the udf be an efficient solution for large data?

Comment: UDF is not  inefficient the only difference is spark won't be able to generate optimised code for UDF ( catalyst optimiser )  logic at runtime it will execute the UDF as it is .

Comment: i agree with you but i think the Reduce function will be more optimal for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say **df** is your initial data frame below code filter the way you are expecting.

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    UDF3<WrappedArray<Integer>,Integer,Integer,List<Integer>> filterFunction =  (WrappedArray<Integer> input, Integer filtVal1,Integer filtVal2) -> {
        List<Integer> newLst= new ArrayList<>(JavaConversions.asJavaList(input));
        newLst.removeIf(x -> x==filtVal1 || x==filtVal2);
        return newLst;
    };

    sparkSession.udf().register("filterFunction", filterFunction, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType));

    Dataset<Row> filteredDf= df.withColumn("Set_temp", functions.callUDF("filterFunction", df.col("Set"),functions.lit(3),functions.lit(4))).drop("Set").withColumnRenamed("Set_temp", "Set").filter("size(Set_temp)>0");

    filteredDf.show();

  +-----+---------+
  |Text2|      Set|
   +-----+---------+
  |  one|[1, 5, 2]|
  |  six|      [5]|
  | five|   [5, 2]|
  +-----+---------+
```

Comment: You can just use `withColumn("set" , ...)` instead of creating a temp, dropping the old and renaming the temp to old name

Comment: why i am concerning that is a better solution with spark 2.2.0?

Comment: Seems like there is no inbuilt function for removal of elements from array so used udf, if we have one then we can use it, also if it's scala then we can eliminate the overhead of conversions.

Comment: When modifying column it's just practice to use drop and rename methods in combination we can directly override the data using withColumn , there won't be much difference in the performance as they are metadata operations.

Comment: i mark the answer as accepted but i want from you to do me a favor can y fix you code to pass dynamically 3 and 4 to the udf is this possible?

Comment: Edited the code in my reply to pass filter values as arguments to UDF